# Disadvantages of using custom patched kernel

Tags: kernel

On my dell laptop I have to use tuxonice to get hibernation and suspend work because default kernel and uswsusp is not working for me. tuxonice is working good. But I want to know that what are disadvantages of custom patched kernel. Am I going to get the updates ? What if where Natty will be released, is it going to break my whole system ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you can install multiple kernels at one time, you will be fine when upgrading to Natty.  The upgrader will basically ignore that you have a custom kernel and proceed normally.

As for getting updates, that is up to the maintainer of the custom kernel to put the work in to keep the kernel uptodate.  Typically the goal of a custom patch maintainer is to provide the patch against the latest Ubuntu kernel.  I use tuxonice myself, and they (the tuxonice maintainers) are very good at pushing out updates.

It is generally a good idea to feel free to install whatever custom kernels you want and keep around the standard kernel, just-in-case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, It was very informative. I was just worried because I have received any update in last 6 to 7 days, but may be thats because of the holiday season.What you think ?

Comment: The updates for tuxonice will always follow the release schedule for the mainline kernel.  And that schedule tends to be a bit random; I'm sure they just release whenever needed.  I have found the tuxonice gets released very close to the mainline releases.  No need to worry!